# Bigquery Wildcard characters

Tags: google-bigquery, wildcard, wildcard-expansion

I have two tables say SAMPLE_CODE, and SAMPLE_CODE_TYPE along with several tables. There are 21 rows in SAMPLE_CODE and 4 rows in SAMPLE_CODE_TYPE. Both table has similar column say
code_type STRING. Other than that all column schema are different. When I query

SELECT * FROM
`MYPROJECT.MYDATASET.SAMPLE*
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX = '_CODE'

-- Here I have hardcoded the '_CODE' value but actually this value
comes from another subquery. But the one I have hardcoded is not
giving the desired output.
-- I want this query to select SAMPLE_CODE table but the output of this query is not so. It prints 21 rows of the SAMPLE_CODE_TYPE while there are only 4 rows in that table and 21 rows in SAMPLE_CODE table.  Is it kind of mix matching between two tables? How is this possible ?
Can any one tell me what should I do to the query so that it fetches the values of the SAMPLE_CODE table based on _TABLE_SUFFIX value. what am I missing here?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LIKE` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `MYPROJECT.MYDATASET.SAMPLE`
WHERE `_TABLE_SUFFIX` LIKE '%\\_CODE%';
```